# Apache URL rewrite question

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Hello 
I want to redirect all the requests to url  example.com/rock/apps to example.com/rock/apps/webroot using Apache rewrite rules but the main thing is I do not want webroot come in to my url

Right now I have written this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ webroot [NC,L]
```

Which provides example.com/rock/apps/webroot

How to eliminate that webroot from the end ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use mod_alias in conjunction with the rewrite. Instead of webroot use some other dummy path and alias that dummy path to webroot.

Answer (score 0):

your conditions...

RewriteRule ^(rock/apps)/webroot$ $1